# Bit operation makes signed integer become unsigned

Tags: go, casting, bit, signed

Computer uses two's complement to store integers. Say, for int32 signed, 0xFFFFFFFF represents '-1'. According to this theory, it is not hard to write such code in C to init a signed integer to -1;

```
int a = 0xffffffff;
printf("%d\n", a);
```

Obviously, the result is `-1`.

**However**, in Go, the same logic dumps differently.

```
a := int(0xffffffff)
fmt.Printf("%d\n", c)
```

The code snippet prints `4294967295`, the maximum number an uint32 type can hold. Even if I cast `c` explicitly in `fmt.Printf("%d\n", int(c))`, the result is still the same.

The same problem happens when some bit operations are imposed on signed integer as well, make signed become unsigned.

So, what happens to Go in such a situation?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that size of `int` is not fixed, it is platform dependent. It may be 32 or 64 bits. In the latter case assigning `0xffffffff` to it is equivalent to assigning `4294967295` to it, which is what you see printed.

Now if you convert that value to `int32` (which is 32-bit), you'll get your `-1`:

```
a := int(0xffffffff)
fmt.Printf("%d\n", a)

b := int32(a)
fmt.Printf("%d\n", b)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playgroung](https://play.golang.org/p/GMF2ceaI6Jr)):

```
4294967295
-1
```

Also note that in Go it is not possible to assign `0xffffffff` directly to a value of type `int32`, because the value would overflow; nor it is valid to create a typed constant having an illegal value, such as `int32(0xffffffff)`. [Spec: Constants:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions)

> The values of *typed* constants must always be accurately [representable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Representability) by values of the constant type.

So this gives a compile-time error:

```
var c int32 = 0xffffffff // constant 4294967295 overflows int32
```

But you may simply do:

```
var c int32 = -1
```

You may also do:

```
var c = ^int32(0) // -1
```